# Integer cannot be converted to type Integer()?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, type-conversion

My code is meant to sort out a record array thingo numerically through calling a subroutine in another part of my program, but for some reason it is not accepting the input which is not letting it compile.

I have an array called materials() that holds things such as IDs and names but when I call the subroutine quicksort(list(), first, last), it gives an error that type Integer cannot be converted to type Integer().

Is there a difference between the two types? and how am I able to fix this so that it sorts the IDs?

CODE:

```
prgFunctions.quickSortInt(materials(numMatFile).matID, 1, numMatFile)
```

which calls:

```
Public Shared Sub quickSortInt(ByRef list() As Integer, ByVal first As Integer, ByVal last As Integer)

        'FIX THIS list() needs to match somehow with the array being called

        'Low is the beginning index, high is the final index initially. Midvalue is between both.
        Dim high, low, midValue As Integer
        low = first
        high = last
        midValue = list((first + last) \ 2)

        'Function sorts by comparing the value at low to the mid value, and if it is less than it 
        'ignores and steps up the index.
        Do
            While list(low) < midValue
                low = low + 1
            End While

            'Repeat for the high value but step down the index.
            While list(high) > midValue
                high = high - 1
            End While

            'When both while loops have finished (ie. low value is equal to or higher than the 
            'mid and vice versa for high) it checks whether the low index is less than or equal 
            'to the high index, then swaps the values.
            If low <= high Then
                swapInt(list(low), list(high))
                low = low + 1
                high = high - 1
            End If

            'Loop while the low index is less than or equal to the high index
        Loop While low <= high

        'When the first index is less than the high index, use recursion to sort new sublists
        If first < high Then
            quickSortInt(list, first, high)
        End If

        'Same for low and last
        If low < last Then
            quickSortInt(list, low, last)
        End If
    End Sub
```

Sorry for the mess of code, I copied most of it from a really old 2003 forum post and fixed it so it works normally, but it is not working in this instance. I am also kind of new to coding as well. Thanks for helping!

Comment: I don't have time to post a full answer but `ByRef list() As Integer` in the function declaration means it takes an array, whereas when you call it you are passing a single ID -> `matID`

Comment: Is it actually your intention to sort `materials` by the `matID` field/property of the elements?  If so then that method is not going to do it for you because it can only sort an `Integer` array.  Also, there's no good reason to be declaring that parameter `ByRef` as nowhere do you assign anything to it.

Comment: is `matID` an integer or a collection of integers?

Comment: yeah I wanted to sort `materials` by the `matID` property, but I'm not really too sure how to go around it as I have only done basic arrays with the quicksort algorithm. @jmcilhinney

Comment: `matID` is just a single integer within a `material` record, but they all have different values @Jaxi

Comment: Just want to add, I had the same issues even when I converted the record `materials(index).matID` to a single array so when calling the function with `temparray(numMatFile)` in place of what I have now causes the same issue

Comment: If you want your method to sort an array of whatever type `materials` is then you need your method to take an array of that type, not type `Integer`. Inside the method, you need to compare the `matID` properties of the elements rather than comparing the elements themselves.

Comment: Your code is very confusing, are you trying to sort `materials` array by MatID? The signature states `ByRef list() As Integer, ByVal first As Integer, ByVal last As Integer` which means by reference integer array, then a normal integer, and another integer, although you seem to be passing 3 integers to the function by the sounds of it.

Comment: Also, you can use LINQ and `OrderBy` to sort your list without a massive subroutine. Example: `materials = materials.OrderBy(Function(x) x.matID).ToList()`

Comment: unfortunately I have to use a 'complex function' so I can't simplify it @Jaxi

Comment: I did try changing it to a `material` type and that seems to have fixed the issue but not I am having index out of range exceptions and things :/ but that's a different issue altogether @jmcilhinney

Comment: Ah, fair enough.